# How to update software inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, updates

I am very new to Docker and currently trying to get my head around if there is any best practice guide to update software that runs inside a docker container in a very large distributed environment. I already found couple of posts around updating a MySQL database in docker, etc. It gives a good hint for any software that stores data, but what if you want to update other parts or your own software package or services that are distributed and used by several other docker images through docker-compose?

Is there someone with real life experience doing that in such an environment who can help me or other newbies to understand the best practices in docker if there are any.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

You never update software in a running container. You pull down a new version from the [hub](https://hub.docker.com/). If we assume you're using the latest tag (which is a bad idea, always pin your versions) of your image and it's one of the official library images or the publicly available that uses automated builds you'll get the latest version of the container image when you pull the image.

This assume you've also separated the data out of your container either as a host volume or using the data container pattern.

The container should be considered immutable, if you change it's state it's no longer a true version of the image.

Comment: What if you have many tiny containers composed with docker-composer that builds your software? Are these changes w/ or w/o downtime? In a best case I want to have no downtime

Comment: If part of the Dockerfile relating to the build calls in your `docker-compose.yml` involves downloading and compiling source code or upgrading through the package manager, you'll trigger a new image. Re: no downtime - can you post the your `docker-compose.yml`, it might aid me in improving my answer.

Comment: So far it's more a theoretical question rather than something I am doing in practice yet. Just thinking about a more large distributed environment example and not the single docker image example. Upgrading through the package manager you mean you basically connect to the image via ssh and execute, for example, `npm`? Would you do all of that in the running container, or would you use a different image/container version and just "magically" switch out the running with the new version?